# Registering a User in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Currently admin's credentials are used to regsiter a user generating cert and private key which is stored in a single system. Both admin keys and user keys are accessible to anyone on a system where dockers are present. In a Production environment how to isolate and secure these certs and keys Because Blockchain is never hacked but the wallet is...

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to leverage an HSM (hardware security module) to store such material. Hyperledger Fabric supports HSMs that implement the PKCS11 standard API (though we do not publish images with PKCS11 support enabled by default, you would need to build a set of images with the appropriate compile flag).